# UIAlertController not allowing click

Tags: objective-c, ios8

I am generating a UIAlertController for use in iOS8 to replace a UIActionSheet function.

The controller presents correctly, but I cannot click anywhere in the controller to get a response. I put in simple NSLog into the handler, and it is absolutely not firing.

Can anyone shed some light on this problem?

BTW, in iOS8 the UIActionSheet is ALSO not generating click events, but in iOS7 this works fine with absolutely no code change.

here is the code:

```
    NSString *alertMessage = @"How do you wish to share ?";
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Share Image"
                                                                   message:alertMessage
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    // You can add as many actions as you want
    UIAlertAction *emailShare = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Share using email"
                                                              style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                            handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                                NSLog(@"EMAIL");
                                                            }];

    UIAlertAction *smShare = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Share using twitter/facebook"
                                                              style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                            handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                                [self actionSheet:nil didDismissWithButtonIndex:1];
                                                            }];

    UIAlertAction *cancelShare = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"cancel"
                                                      style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                        [self actionSheet:nil didDismissWithButtonIndex:2];
                                                    }];

    // Add actions to the controller so they will appear
    [alertController addAction:emailShare];
    [alertController addAction:smShare];
    [alertController addAction:cancelShare];

    // Finally present the action
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few different issues with your code. I've commented on the changes that are necessary. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
// No need to create a NSString. Just set the message.
// NSString *alertMessage = @"How do you wish to share?";

// If you'd like a UIActionSheet use UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet as the preferredStyle
// Opposed to UIAlertControllerStyleAlert, which presents a UIAlertView

UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Share Image"
                                                                         message:@"How do you wish to share?" // Message Set
                                                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet]; // Changed to show action sheet

UIAlertAction *emailShare = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Share using email"
                                                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                       [alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                                       // Call your function here
                                                       // ie. [self emailShare];
                                                       NSLog(@"First Button");
                                                   }];
UIAlertAction *smShare = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Share using twitter/facebook"
                                                  style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                    // [self actionSheet:nil didDismissWithButtonIndex:1];
                                                    // Where did you create actionSheet?
                                                    // didDismissWithButtonIndex: is not neccessary
                                                    // Just simply dismiss the UIAlertController
                                                    [alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                                    // And then call your function here
                                                    // ie. [self twitterShare];
                                                    NSLog(@"Second Button");
                                                }];
UIAlertAction *cancelShare = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                      style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel // Set style to cancel
                                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                        // [self actionSheet:nil didDismissWithButtonIndex:2];
                                                        // Where did you create actionSheet?
                                                        // didDismissWithButtonIndex: is not neccessary
                                                        // Just simply dismiss the UIAlertController
                                                        [alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                                        NSLog(@"Cancel Button");
                                                    }];
[alertController addAction:emailShare];
[alertController addAction:smShare];
[alertController addAction:cancelShare];

[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: i appreciate you looking at the code. I know i can clean this code up substantially, by getting rid of the creation of the NSString for example, but honestly that is not the issue here.  If you notice the first action, it is an NSLog in the handler. This is not getting called.  actionSheet is a function further down in my code - which is irrelevant since i cannot get an NSlog to fire. I know i could crete this as an action sheet by invoking the Popover, but i was just trying to get this to work at all. Is there anything you can see that would prevent the tapping? I am presenting correctly.

Comment: here is a screenshot - i created this as a popover and it did not change anything... still cannot click - oops - cannot find a way to add the screen shot.